# Concatenating XML Element Values to String using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Given an XML Document - for instance:

```
<factory>
    <widgets>
        <widget>Foo</widget>
        <widget>Bar</widget>
        <widget>Baz</widget>
        <widget>Qux</widget>
    </widgets>
</factory>
```

I wish to build a line-break separated string of widget values - using the above XML, this would be:

```
Foo
Bar
Baz
Qux
```

The code I'm using to do this is:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml) //where XML is a string containing the above XML
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var widget in doc.Root.Element("widgets").Elements("widget"))
{
    builder.AppendLine(widget.Value);
}
```

However, the resulting string is `FooBarBazQux` rather than a newline-separated version. Setting a breakpoint on the AppendLine call reveals that `widget.Value` is being set to "FooBarBazQux", and the loop runs once rather than the 4 times I'm expecting.

I've tried running the query in LinqPad:

```
XDocument settings = XDocument.Parse (@"
    <factory>
        <widgets>
            <widget>Foo</widget>
            <widget>Bar</widget>
            <widget>Baz</widget>
            <widget>Qux</widget>
        </widgets>
    </factory>");


foreach(var x in settings.Root.Elements("widgets").Elements("widget"))
    x.Value.Dump("Widget Type");
```

and the results are correct and as expected.

Can anyone help me in getting a newline separated string of `Widget` values? I'm at a bit of a loss!

It might be worth noting that this is within a Xamarin.Forms application, using the PCL version of using System.Xml.Linq.

Comment: How are you verifying this?  Your code works fine for me - see https://dotnetfiddle.net/P9YaVx

Comment: Catenation of all 4 values at once would happen if you selected an ancestor element's value / text, e.g. `builder.AppendLine(doc.Root.Element("widgets").Value)` in your example would do this. Note that xml is case sensitive so `Widgets` <> `widgets`. Also remember to call `.ToString()` on your StringBuilder for the final output.

Comment: I've just tried writing a minimal-viable-example demo app, and this code is indeed working... how strange. Perhaps my problem is elsewhere in my code. I'll investigate. Oh, and yes - sorry StuartLC, I've fixed those mistakes now.

Comment: I've realized what the problem was, and have added it as an answer - I think it was a combination of two problems (one of which being that mentioned by StuartLC).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I should add it as an answer so it can be marked as such (or if I will get shouted at because I have already put it in a comment)

builder.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

This was a stupid mistake, caused by "Fast Deployment" being enabled in the Android Xamarin project.

My XML File was being generated by the app if it didn't exist - I assumed that on re-deploying, all app assets were to being removed from the device. It turns out that when Fast Deployment is enabled, the device only updates NEW components of the application - i.e. the XML file wasn't being removed. The problem was caused by the XML file being out of date.

I believe that the XML document being initially incorrect was caused by the potential issue that StuartLC pointed out - I must have at one point called `builder.AppendLine(doc.Root.Element("widgets").Value)`, which returns the concatenation of the value of all child elements of widgets.

Thanks for all the help!